# bitwise math regarding actionscript tags in swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to intelligently parse actionscript tags, Ive check the source for several open source programs that disassemble/decompile swf files.

Checking [the doc](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) on pg29 it states

> "Note: The TagCodeAndLength field is a two-byte word, not a bit field of 10 bits followed by a bit field of 6 bits.
>   The little-endian byte ordering of a SWF file makes these two layouts different."

Checking in 010 Editor, the first tag is

```
0x44 0x11
```

which somehow translates to 0x45 (then the length). However, by the doc (quoted above), it doesnt make any sense as it appears to be:

```
0100 0100 0001 0001
```

which doesnt even remotely appear to be

```
0110 1001
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: I did this myself, but it has been quite sime time ago. Can you post the bytecode with the tag you are parsing?

Comment: I don't have my code handy now, so it's hard to say exactly what's happening, but anyway, LE order means that `0100 0100 0001 0001` should be interpreted as `0001 0001 0100 0100`, which is a short header for tag `1000101` (69 or 0x45 ) with a length of `100` (4).

Comment: @NoxNoctis I thought it was supposed to be 69h not 45h (the doc wasnt too clear if tags were hex or dec vals). I edited my question to reflect that. can you give an official answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: Ok. Building a parser is a tedious task I must add. Caused me quite a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LE order means that a two-byte value `0100 0100` `0001 0001` should be read as `0001 0001` `0100 0100` (byte order reversed), which is a short header for tag `1000101` (0x45, dec 69) with a length of 0x100 (dec 4).